# Is there any way to increase 'realmax' in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

realmax on my machine is:

> 1.7977e+308

I know I have to write my code in a way to avoid long integer calculations, but is there any way to increase the limit?
I mean something like gmp library in C

Comment: I don't think you can increase that. What you can do is use [`vpa`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (or, if possible, modify your code to avoid overflow)

Comment: Agree with Luis Mendo. BTW, very nice display picture!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find [`vpa`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html) (**variable- precision arithmetic**) helpful:

> `R = vpa(A)` uses variable-precision arithmetic (VPA) to compute each element of `A` to at least `d` decimal digits of accuracy, where `d` is the current setting of `digits`.
>
> `R = vpa(A,d)` uses at least `d` significant (nonzero) digits, instead of the current setting of `digits`.

Here's an example how to use it:

```
>> x = vpa('10^500/20')
ans =
5.0e498
```

Note that:

- The **output** `x` is of **symbolic** ([`sym`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/symbolic-objects.html)) type. Of course, you shouldn't convert it to `double`, because it would exceed `realmax`:

  ```
  >> double(x)
  ans =
     Inf
  ```
- Use **string input** in order to avoid evaluating large input values as `double`. For example, this doesn't work

  ```
  >> vpa(10^500/20)
  ans =
  Inf
  ```

  because `10^500` is evaluated as `double`, giving `inf`, and *then* is used as an input to `vpa`.

Comment: In case `vpa` is not available, the [Multiple Precision Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/6446-multiple-precision-toolbox-for-matlab) offers an alternative.